# A homogeneous system $Ax = 0$ with $\det(A) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have $Ax = 0$ with a **square matrix** $A$. I tried to prove the following:

> $\det(A) = 0$ iff the system $Ax = 0$ is inconsistent.

I am not sure if I misunderstood the consistency definition. My intuition is: If at least there is one solution, then the system is consistent. If there is NO solution and if one can derive a contradiction from equations, then the system is inconsistent. In the case of $Ax = 0$, there is always a solution $x = \mathbf{0}$. It means that system is always  consistent. Then, I suppose I have to simply disprove this argument.

But I am not sure about that, so I am here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many solutions since $A$ have a non-trivial kernel hence there is $v\neq 0$ s.t $Av=0$.

Comment: @Belgi: You consider $A$ as a transformation?

Comment: My hunch is the author uses "consistent := unique solution."

Comment: @BabakS. - Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. I suspect it should read $\det(A)=0$ if and only if the system $Ax=0$ is not independent (has more than one solution).

Comment: Thanks Cameron. In the original question, it says inconsistent. Inconsistency of the systems is defined as follows: "A system is inconsistent if it has no solutions." Does $Ax = 0$ has always a solution? (including all pathological cases?)

Comment: Yes, you were correct that $x=0$ always works. Non-homogeneous systems can be inconsistent, but homogeneous systems never are.